# Simplest way to run an authenticated SMTP server on Linux?

Tags: linux, smtp

What is the simplest way I can get a secure, authenticated SMTP server running on my Linux machine so my family can use it to send mail from hostile networks?

Currently I have exim bound to `127.1:25` so if I can send mail from my laptop using `ssh -L2525:localhost:25 wolever.net`… But I'd like exim (or some other SMTP server) to bind to, eg, `0.0.0.0:2525` and accept authenticated SMTP connections.

What's the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your family's sending over 500 messages a day, just use [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html). It's free and works extremely well.

You can use their SMTP servers to send from wherever. Since they're reputable, your messages are unlikely to be marked as spam... Especially if you setup an [SFP record](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33786))

Comment: There are two reasons I'd rather not use them: 0) they won't let me use an arbitrary port (and ISPs around here block smtp/smtp+tls), 1) I believe they will require that I validate the source addresses (which is a problem for me, as I use a bunch of different “from” addresses).

Comment: I'm not sure they will validate the from address as email as a protocol astonishingly doesn't have a facility/requirement for that. Actually, I'm pretty damn sure I use a gmail account to send mail "from" somewhere that doesn't have anything to do with the account. As for the lame ISPs, I guess you could use SSH tunnels to locally open those ports. SSH tunnels pwn.